# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' beautiful soup /request and none output

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://www.amazon.com/HGLRC-Freestyle-Controller-Quadcopters-Multirotors/dp/B07Z1BFTVQ/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=freestyle+drone&qid=1605895415&sr=8-5"
headers = {"user-agent":    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

title = soup.find(id ="productTitle").get_text()
print(title.strip)
```

Comment: Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your script, and can see the issue; you're not getting the response you're expecting because the scrape is being blocked by Amazon

Before you scrape a website, you need to check their **robots.txt** to see if you're allowed to; [here](https://www.amazon.com/robots.txt) is the link to it for Amazon, which as you can see has a lot of **Disallows** in it

What's actually being returned is a robot challenge (see below), and therefore the following part of your code is returning a **NoneType**

```
soup.find(id ="productTitle")
```

Then finally, **get_text()** throws the **AttributeError**

[image]